# process crashes, no log file where it says

Tags: octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I change some parameters in some `octomap_server` initialization code, I get a crash which I can't debug.

```
[octomap_server-2] process has died [pid 22734, exit code -6, cmd /home/chris/ros_ws/devel/lib/octomap_server/octomap_server_node cloud_in:=/cloud __name:=octomap_server __log:=/home/chris/.ros/log/798b4038-b889-11e4-97b4-b8ca3a7c5dcb/octomap_server-2.log].
log file: /home/chris/.ros/log/798b4038-b889-11e4-97b4-b8ca3a7c5dcb/octomap_server-2*.log\
```

I would normally just use the log file it tells me, but for the node that crashed there is no log file in the directory it specifies. I have grep'd all the source code for `exit(-6)` etc and can't find anything. Any suggestions how I can actually see why its crashing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203454/process-crashes,-no-log-file-where-it-says/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try running the process through a debugger? E.g, if you are using a roslaunch file, try adding gdb to the launch-prefix.
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on 2015-02-19**:
wasn't aware of this, this explains everything.